# Proper use of array of const char* in getsubopt

Tags: arrays, pointers, enums, char, constants

I am trying to use getsubopt to parse some suboptions in c++. I have the following code.

```
enum LOG_LEVELS {LOG_QUIET, LOG_NORMAL, LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_DEBUG};

int parse_log_level(char *log_level){
    /* Define valid log options. */
    char *const log_opts[] =
    {
        "quiet",
        "normal",
        "verbose",
        "debug",
        NULL
    }; /* <- First set of warnings */

    char* value;
    /* Loop through each option and check for valid log options. */
    while (log_level != '\0'){
        switch (getsubopt (&log_level, log_opts, &value))
        {
            case LOG_QUIET:
                return LOG_QUIET;
                break;

            case LOG_NORMAL:
                return LOG_NORMAL;
                break;

            case LOG_VERBOSE:
                return LOG_VERBOSE;
                break;

            case LOG_DEBUG:
                return LOG_DEBUG;
                break;

            default:
                std::cout << "Only the following log options are valid"
                          << std::endl << std::endl << "\tquiet"
                          << std::endl << "\tnormal"
                          << std::endl << "\tverbose"
                          << std::endl << "\tdebug" << std::endl;
                return -1;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to compile I get the following error.

```
option_parser.cpp: In function 'int parse_log_level(char*)':
option_parser.cpp:35: warning: deprecated conversion from string const to 'char*'
option_parser.cpp:35: warning: deprecated conversion from string const to 'char*'
option_parser.cpp:35: warning: deprecated conversion from string const to 'char*'
option_parser.cpp:35: warning: deprecated conversion from string const to 'char*'
```

As you may notice, I have deviated somewhat what the example provided at the following:
[getsubopt example](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsubopt)

Namely, I have used:

```
char *const log_opts[] =
{
     "quiet",
     "normal",
     "verbose",
     "debug",
     NULL
}; /* <- First set of warnings */
```

in place of what I imagine would be their version of my code:

```
char *const log_opts[] = 
{
     [LOG_QUIET] = "quiet", /* <- New error */
     [LOG_NORMAL] = "normal", /* <- New error */
     [LOG_VERBOSE] = "verbose", /* <- New error */
     [LOG_DEBUG] = "debug", /* <- New error */
     NULL
};
```

When I try the above code I get the following errors

```
option_parser.cpp: In function 'int parse_log_level(char*)':
option_parser.cpp:30: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
option_parser.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
option_parser.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
option_parser.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
```

I opted for my format over the tutorial's because it avoids the error and I do not understand the syntax, namely I do not understand the `[FOO] = "bar"` syntax within the declaration for the array of char *const. I notice too that in the example their enum is not named whereas my equivalent `LOG_LEVELS` is. My enum works elsewhere in my program. Lastly, I notice that their enum has a similar syntax for the first item, namely `RO_OPT = 0,` within the context of `enum {RO_OPT = 0, RW_OPT, NAME_OPT};`.

I have tried looking for similar constructs elsewhere online but have not found anything that has helped me to solve this problem. I hope I was not too verbose in my attempt to ask the question as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The prototype for `getsubopt` is, in my opinion, incorrect. `tokens` should be a `const char * const *`. Presumably it's a historical error which can't be easily corrected.

There are a couple of ugly ways to work around this.

You can create local, non-const char arrays for each of the options:

```
char tok_quiet[] = "quiet";
char tok_normal[] = "normal";
char tok_verbose[] = "verbose";
char tok_debug[] = "debug";
char *const log_opts[] =
{
    tok_quiet,
    tok_normal,
    tok_verbose,
    tok_debug,
    NULL
};
```

Or you can use literal arrays for the tokens:

```
char *const log_opts[] =
{
    (char[]){'q','u','i','e','t',0},
    (char[]){'n','o','r','m','a','l',0},
    (char[]){'v','e','r','b','o','s','e',0},
    (char[]){'d','e','b','u','g',0},
    NULL
};
```

I think you'll agree that both of these are pretty distasteful.

Given those choices, I'd probably just disable the -Wwrite-strings warning for that section of code using a pragma.

(The other code you referred to, e.g. `[LOG_QUIET] = "quiet"`, uses C99 syntax which is not currently supported in C++. The `[]=` syntax allows you to initialize members of an array by index.)